# In python, how can I replace first value of a series of matrices by a random number?

Tags: python, random, simulation, distribution, uniform

I want to simulate **N** people and each for **T** amount of time, currently I have that the value of **p** for each person at **T=0** is **0**. How can I write this, so instead of having zeros at the first time period, I have a random number that is chosen from a distribution with the other values remaining equal?

```
N = 100
T = 70
p[N,T] 
p[:,0] = 0.0
```

[image: Like this]

Comment: could you clarify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sure, in this case **p** is an attribute of each person, and it starts with **0** in the first time period and then it evolves accordingly but I want that first value to be a random number from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change the 1st value of the 2D array from a value taken from an early defined array you can follow this way. I have added an example for your reference.

```
p = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]]
array = [0.6, 0.5, 0.9]
for i in range(len(p)):
    if p[i][0] == 0:
        p[i][0] = array[i]  # use random() if you want to replace with a random number
print(p)
```

output: [[0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0.9, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help.